# Элементы RecyclerView заезжают под AppCompatButton

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview, разметка, android-relativelayout

Есть разметка фрагмента:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".presentation.Tabs.Card.ShoppingCart">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/clearCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin = "20dp"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/clearCard" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clearCard"
                android:layout_below="@id/clearCard"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTotalOrder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/listCard"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/totalOrder"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/totalOrder"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:layout_below="@id/listCard"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/totalOrder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/listCard"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/currTotalOrder"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:layout_below="@id/listCard"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/headerTotalOrder"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/currTotalOrder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:text="@string/ruble"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/listCard"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/totalOrder"
                android:layout_below="@id/listCard"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/checkoutCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/checkout"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Не смотря на то, что я выставил значение `android:layout_weight` для всех элементов `RecyclerView` заезжает под кнопку, находящуюся под ним

Comment: Вместо `RelativeLayout` используй `LinearLayout`

Comment: @DrMcSheen, попробовал, теперь RecyclerView просто вытесняет кнопку с экрана

Comment: RelativeLayout вообще удалить надо, ни на что не меняя, и сделать всё внутри ConstraintLayout

Comment: @IR42, в этом случае RecyclerView заезжает под кнопку